# How to set condition to true in Dialogflow CX

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I'm going through the Dialogflow CX tutorial and can't seem to understand how to set a condition to true.

From the tutorial:

[tut p.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpRv4.png)

From the reference:

[tut p.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZuGt.png)

I simply don't get the how and where I'm supposed to set this condition to true?

I have the following flow working as intended, except for the "true condition above".

[Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otGsZ.png)

That is, if the user provides full info we go to the confirmation page. If the user provides partial info, the user is prompted for the missing info. I recognize it sounds a lot like it's all good, but I'm missing this step from the full conversation flow:

[Conversation flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XId1.png)

Comment: Setting the condition to true = true seems to do the trick for one conversation turn, but I can hardly believe that is what Google means in their tutorial, albeit making for a better user experience, being told the same thing only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set a condition to true, please utilize the “Customize expression” condition rule.
As seen below, this will automatically trigger the conditional route every time the page is active.

[image: Condition Rules]